# Bundle product item drop down option value not showing in order

Tags: magento-1.7, bundled-product

I am using magento 1.7.1 , Currently i am facing an issue with bundle product items. Its a drop down selection of choosing the size and color, Size options with is not showing up in order, For ex : 55 , 40 50 . I want to show the dropdown like 45 , 50 , 55 . Any idea how can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Bundle selections are not ordered by their label. You have to set the order explicitly:

[image: screensht]

Comment: Yes thanks fshmengler By setting up positing it will fix the issue, Thanks.
Additional i am facing another issue in my shop, When i try to add new simple product and assign that to bundle product the product option is not showing out, Any idea , I have tried with magneto cache  clear , reindex through shell , But not get fixed.

Comment: No. Please post a new question, but provide more details what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Yes sure i will post the new question